# Python | Get range based on value

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get below -
Input -
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F42rq.png)

and Output -
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMI3P.png)

I tried to use shift but I am not getting the result

```
df1['Value_shift_down'] = df1['Value'].shift(-1)
df1['Value_shift_up'] = df1['Value'].shift(1)
```

Comment: Please post the input and output as code.

Comment: Also explain how the new columns df['Value_shift_down'] and df['Value_shift_up'] relate to your expected output.  Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track with pandas `.shift()`. Instead of converting back and forth between strings and integers, you can leverage [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to compare each value with the previous, then use a cumulative sum ([`.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)) to detect when the value changes. The final element is the DataFrame [`.groupby()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), which allows us to collect groups of same-`Value` rows together and get the start and end `Unit`s for that group. The code to do this goes something like this:

```py
result_groups = []
for _, group in df1.groupby((df1["Value"] != df1["Value"].shift()).cumsum()):
    start_unit = group.loc[group.index.min(), "Unit"]
    end_unit = group.loc[group.index.max(), "Unit"]
    value = group["Value"].unique()[0]
    result_groups.append({"Start_Unit": start_unit, "End_Unit": end_unit, "Value": value})
results = pd.DataFrame(result_groups)
```

The `results` DataFrame looks like this, as desired:

|  | **Start_Unit** | **End_Unit** | **Value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Unit 1 | Unit 1 | 2 |
| 1 | Unit 2 | Unit 2 | 4 |
| 2 | Unit 3 | Unit 3 | 1 |
| 3 | Unit 4 | Unit 5 | 5 |
| 4 | Unit 6 | Unit 6 | 7 |
| 5 | Unit 7 | Unit 7 | 6 |
| 6 | Unit 8 | Unit 8 | 9 |
| 7 | Unit 9 | Unit 20 | 0 |

Note: This solution does not require uniqueness of the values in the `'Value'` column on a group-by-group basis (i.e., if there was another sequence of `5`s later, it would correctly recognize it as a new group). If you know ahead of time that this will never happen, you can take a simpler approach, using just `df1.groupby("Value")` instead and doing something similar inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much :-). (df["Value"] != df["Value"].shift()).cumsum() gave the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Determinging the lowest and higest value based on a string is not possible (because "10" is smaller then "2"). Therefore you need to replace your strings by integers.

So one solution might be to remove the unit names and convert the unit name numbers to integers. Then you can determine the min and max values by a pivot table.

```
df['Unit'] = df['Unit'].str.replace('Unit ', '', regex=False).astype(int)
df.pivot_table(index='Value', values='Unit', aggfunc=['min', 'max'])
```

If neccessary, you can convert afterwards the values back to string and add the unit name.

Comment: I don't think that any kind of string conversion is necessary. Just look at the first and last values in the left column corresponding to each grouping of the right column.

Comment: Also, this solution only works if the `'Value'`s are not repeated later on.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I am sorry; my question was unclear, but the repeated value is getting grouped incorrectly. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75514362/2739110) solved this issue.